# CMAKE in requirements.txt file: Install llama-cpp-python for Mac

Tags: python, macos, llama-cpp-python, llamacpp

I have put my application into a Docker and therefore I have created a requirements.txt file. Now I need to install `llama-cpp-python` for Mac, as I am loading my LLM with from langchain.llms import LlamaCpp.

My installation command specifically for Mac is:

`"CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL=on" FORCE_CMAKE=1 pip install llama-cpp-python"`

But it does not work if I put this in my "requirements.txt" file.

My requirements.txt file looks as follows:

```
chromadb==0.4.14
langchain==0.0.354
pandas==2.0.3
python-dotenv==1.0.0
python_box==7.1.1
PyYAML==6.0.1
streamlit==1.29.0
torch==2.1.0
sentence-transformers==2.2.2
faiss-cpu==1.7.4
CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL=on" FORCE_CMAKE=1 pip install llama-cpp-python # Does not work like this
```

My Dockerfile looks like this after the comment of @ivvija :

```
FROM python:3.11.5
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL=on" FORCE_CMAKE=1 pip install llama-cpp-python
EXPOSE 8501
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8501/_stcore/health
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "streamlit_app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```

Which results in this error: `ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

How can I do this?

Comment: `CMAKE_ARGS` is an environment variable and supplied this way on shells but not inside a requirements.txt. I think the best would be removing it from the req.txt and adding a new line in the Dockerfile for `CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL=on" FORCE_CMAKE=1 pip install llama-cpp-python` like in the [examples](https://github.com/abetlen/llama-cpp-python/blob/main/docker/cuda_simple/Dockerfile).

Comment: when putting it into the Dockerfile,  it fails with error: "ERROR: Could not build wheels for llama-cpp-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects". I will add my Dockerfile in my question

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution:
In your Dockerfile add the llama-cpp-python installation for MAc like this:

```
FROM python:3.11.5
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV RUN CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL=on" FORCE_CMAKE=1
RUN pip install llama-cpp-python
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8501
HEALTHCHECK CMD curl --fail http://localhost:8501/_stcore/health
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "streamlit_app.py", "--server.port=8501", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]
```